# Force close of app when clicking send button

Tags: php, android, android-asynctask

I am developing an android app which connects to a remote MySQL database with PHP script hosted on that server.My android app is for registration purpose .It passes two strings from android to MySQL database.When i wrote it the and installed on mobile app is force closing after clicking send button in that registration form.The error is below. Any one help me for solving

> 05-31 13:17:55.758  13875-13978/? E/AndroidRuntime? FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
>           Process: com.example.naveen.e_complaint, PID: 13875
>           java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
>                   at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
>                   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
>                   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
>                   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
>                   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>            Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
>                   at com.example.naveen.e_complaint.childprotection$CreateNewProduct.doInBackground(childprotection.java:83)
>                   at com.example.naveen.e_complaint.childprotection$CreateNewProduct.doInBackground(childprotection.java:63)
>                   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
>                   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>                   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>       05-31 13:17:58.738  13875-13875/? E/WindowManager? android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.naveen.e_complaint.childprotection has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{15abb8ab V.E..... R......D 0,0-456,174} that was originally added here
>                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.(ViewRootImpl.java:363)
>                   at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:271)
>                   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
>                   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:298)
>                   at com.example.naveen.e_complaint.childprotection$CreateNewProduct.onPreExecute(childprotection.java:75)
>                   at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:591)
>                   at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:539)
>                   at com.example.naveen.e_complaint.childprotection$1.onClick(childprotection.java:54)
>                   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
>                   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
>                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
>       05-31 13:18:00.991    1246-1272/system_process E/JavaBinder? !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
>       05-31 13:18:01.006    1246-1330/system_process E/InputDispatcher? channel '23c97e57 com.example.naveen.e_complaint/com.example.naveen.e_complaint.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
>       05-31 13:18:01.016    1246-1330/system_process E/InputDispatcher? channel '312e3255 com.example.naveen.e_complaint/com.example.naveen.e_complaint.childprotection (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
>       05-31 13:18:01.019    1246-1330/system_process E/InputDispatcher? channel '8f330dc com.example.naveen.e_complaint/com.example.naveen.e_complaint.DepartmentsList (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!

Comment: Post ur code to help u in better way

Comment: Your error says itself that your EditText is null

Answer (score 0):

Another error you're going to encounter is the Toast you're trying to show in doInBackground() - Async tasks are run on a non-UI thread, and can't do UI things.